# Django: How to display page serial number in increment order

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I displaying 20 rows of content in a page and i am able to display S.No 1 to 20 and i am using paginator to go next page and to come back previous page when i choose the next page here in each page its showing 1 to 20 only. its not showing when going to next page and its not decreasing while coming to previous page. How to display the S.No in increment order

```
{% for child in children.object_list %}
<tr><td width="15%">strong>Sl.no</strong>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}


<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if children.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ children.next_page_number }}"> Previous </a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ children.number }} of {{ children.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if children.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ children.previous_page_number }}"> Next </a>
        {% endif %}
 <br>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your template write this to show item number

```
{% for child in children.object_list %}
    <tr><td width="15%">strong>Sl.no</strong>
        {{ forloop.counter0|add:children.start_index}} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{forloop.counter}}` will always start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I always use [django-pagination](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination) for this sort of thing. It does all the hard work for you using a couple of template tags...